# Create a file in the userfiles folder (C#, Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, winforms, file

I'm trying to create a text file in my [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. It is working fine, but it is creating the text file in the application's default location (like in folder `bin`). But I want to save that created text file in my user files folder. How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
FileInfo fileusername = new FileInfo("userinfo.txt");
StreamWriter namewriter = fileusername.CreateText();
namewriter.Write(txtUsername.Text);
namewriter.Close();
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) to get the path to the user data folder:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData),
    "userinfo.txt");
```

Look into the documentation of the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enum in order to find the folder that best suits your needs.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [Environment.GetFolderPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/14tx8hby.aspx) function together with the `Environment.SpecialFolder` enumeration.

Use:

```
String filePath = Path.Combine(
    Evironment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments),
    "userinfo.txt");
```

to create the file name in the current users `My Documents` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Environment.SpecialFolder to create a filepath that points to my documents:

```
string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData.ToString(), "userinfo.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the path to the filename, like
FileInfo fileusername = new FileInfo(@"c:\Users\MyUser\Documents\userinfo.txt");

Comment: i want to create in my application folder only (dynamicall)

Comment: Please stay clear from my documents folder as an application. "My Documents" is called like that because *I* create things there, not some random application. There are enough programs that get this wrong already.

Answer (score 1):

String path = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal );

OR

```
String path = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments );
```

Comment: Please stay clear from my documents folder as an application. "My Documents" is called like that because *I* create things there, not some random application. There are enough programs that get this wrong already.

Comment: thank you for your quick response. But I'm sorry i was not frame my question correctly.. i want to create a file in my application forlder only (like c:\\myapp\\usercreatedfiles\ ) here i want to create

Comment: @Nagu: don't do that: this will require the user to have full permissions to the folder in which the application is installed, which is typically not a good thing.

Comment: oh actually i tried with Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() it is working fine for me. Is it not good? then wat is the alternate and good method?

Comment: Nagu: The user's profile for per-user data, the "All users" profile for global data. But careful with stuff that's globally writable for every user.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you simply want to create your text file in a custom directory. My advice would be to create a constant for the path (perhaps saving it in the app.config file).

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="UserInfo" value="/Settings/UserInfo.txt" /> 
</appSettings>
```

Use a relative path to your exe so regardless of where you install your application the settings will always be saved to "PathToExe/Settings/UserInfo.txt".

Then you would do something like:

```
string UserInfoPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserInfo"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserInfoPath))
{
    // perhaps use a default value or raise an exception
}

FileInfo fileusername = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Application.StartUpPath, UserInfoPath));
StreamWriter namewriter = fileusername.CreateText();
namewriter.Write(txtUsername.Text);
namewriter.Close();
```

However, you may come across a permissions issues using this approach, it is usually a better idea to store things like this either in the Registry or in the AppData directory.